# Prove the maximum principle for a solution of the PDE $(-\Delta + \lambda)u=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle, laplacian

Show that if $u$ satisfies $(-\Delta + \lambda)u=0$ in a smooth region $\Omega$ where $\lambda$ is a nonnegative real number, then u satisfies the maximum principle.

We can just assume u is smooth, and actually it is true and can be proved. The statement is that any distribution $u$ satisfies the equation must be smooth, which is done in Treves.

But the point here is to prove if $u$ is smooth, then why $u$ satisfies the maximum principle.

Here is my attempt:

---

The case $\lambda=0$ is trivial, for it is well known that harmonic function satisfies maximum principle. So we assume $\lambda>0 \space.$

If $u$ attains its maximal value in $\Omega$ at $x_0$, then in multivariable calculus we know that $\Delta u(x_0)\le0\space.$ Now we discuss the following two cases:

If $u(x_0)>0$, then $\Delta u=\lambda u>0$ at $x_0$, which contradicts $\Delta u(x_0)\le0\space.$

If $u(x_0)\le0$, then $u\le0$ in $\Omega$, hence $-u\ge0$ in $\Omega$, and $\Delta (-u)=-\lambda u>0$. But it doesn't tell me anything...

---

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @user167839: I think you pretty much did it already. Subharmonic functions also obey the maximum principle (google it!), and if $u\ge 0$ (which I believe you want to assume, but didn't mention), then $\Delta u = \lambda u \ge 0$, so $u$ is subharmonic.

Comment: @Christian Remling, well, there is no assumption in the problem that $u\ge0\space$I've edited my problem to make it clear and I gave up using properties of subharmonic functions.

Comment: The statement looks wrong without such an extra assumption: say $d=1$, then $u=-\cosh x$ solves $-u''+u=0$ and has a maximum at $x=0$.

Comment: @Christian Remling, Wow, thanks very much! I can't believe I spent too much time on this problem.